# ND-Matrix Multiplication, without using numpy.dot

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

Python and coding beginner here. I started learning python a couple of days ago, no prior coding experience, and I've started learning about functions. Since python is really useful for mathematical operations, I'm trying to tie this with what I'm learning in my linear algebra class. So here's the question. Beware a lot of reading ahead!

I'm trying to multiply two random matrices using python, without numpy (otherwise I can use `numpy.dot` and `numpy.matrix`). If we have 2 matrices X and Y, of dimensions axb and bxc respectively, matrix multiplication only works if the columns of X and the rows of Y are equal. In order to write a program that can do the matrix multiplication, here's what I tried.

First I defined my function as `def mat.mul(A,B)`, with dimensions axb and bxc respectively. I then have the matrix Z as the product of the matrix A and B, which will be empty, `Z = []`. Here's where my thought process is a bit wobbly. I think that first I need a for loop that iterates through the columns of A, `for a in range(0, len(A)):`, followed by another for loop that iterates through the rows of A, `for b in range(len(0, X[0]))` , followed by another for loop to iterate through the columns of B, `for c in range(0, len(Y))` and finally a last for loop that iterates through the rows of Y, `for d in range(0, len(Y[0]))`. Now I should have the product matrix Z but I'm not how I should write it. Would it be `Z += X[i] * Y[d]`?

Sorry for the long explanation, I just thought I'd share my thought process as well.

Comment: please write a minimal and reproducible example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should need three indices/loops---as you state, you can multiply matrices of size AxB and BxC. And you iterate over the indices for B together on both sides. So it's more like `Z[a, c] = sum(X[a, b] * Y[b, c] for b in B)` or something.